# Association between three classes

Tags: uml, magic-draw

I have the following situation/ model:

[image]

I have a **Player** class which has a **Color** and a **Figure**. Quite simple. But now I want to give the **Figure** an association to the **Color**:

[image]

Now I'm looking for a way to force the Figure to have the same Color as the Player. Perhaps I'm missing something very obvious, but I don't have any idea how to do it. Is there any OCL expression?

I'm using Magic Draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Figure to have the same Color as the Player"

This is, usually, not handled as a direct association, but, indirectly, by the Player class & its associations.

Its valid to have a "Color" property in "Figure", and add a restriction, that is modeled as a O.C.L. comment / note.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a *ternary association*. UML supports N-ary associations. See [here](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html).

Also, here is a [YouTube video about drawing ternary associations in MagicDraw](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOIQ4hOnneU).

Answer (score 2):

Let Color be an associationClass between the others, so that for every two instances of them, there is a single instance of color, which is what you want.